# Problem Cordova App iOS after update on WKWEBVIEW, not load local file

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I have update my cordova app migrate from UIWebView to **WKWebview** following this tutorial:
https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html

And I have also installed this plugin: "cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix"

When I start the app on emulator iOS, all work fine.

While if I run on phisically device the app **not load local file** e.g. (file:///...../cat_10017.png) an image or text file.

I use:

```
cordova-ios@5.1.1
cordova@8.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to point your image stored in:

> public/img/my-logo.png

this way

```
<image src='/android_asset/www/img/my-logo.png' responsive />
```